# Open .sln file from add-in without reloading Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have developed a Add-in which can list all .sln files in a given folder.

How can I open the .sln file when it is selected from my add-in without reloading Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code if you have a path to a .sln file:

```
if (dte.Solution.IsOpen)
   dte.Solution.Close(true);
dte.Solution.Open(path);
```